# Karate - Gatling - How to add scenario name to REQUEST entries in simulation.log

Tags: karate

I am using Karate-Gatling project and executing gatling simulations, 
My  CatSimulation.scala has different scenario names for same API.

Post run, In gatling simulation.log file, we could see Scenario name in USER log line entries corresponding REQUEST entries doesn't have the Scenario name

Currently, my gatling simulation.log looks like below

```
RUN mock.CatSimulation  catsimulation   1589210870232       3.0.2
USER    AUTHZ   1   START   1589210870336   1589210870336
USER    PRODUCT 3   START   1589210870459   1589210870459
USER    PROV    5   START   1589210870470   1589210870470
USER    LDAP    7   START   1589210870479   1589210870479
USER    SSO 9   START   1589210870490   1589210870490
USER    AUTHZ   2   START   1589210870971   1589210870971
USER    PRODUCT 4   START   1589210870983   1589210870983
USER    PROV    6   START   1589210870993   1589210870993
USER    SSO 10  START   1589210871015   1589210871015
USER    LDAP    8   START   1589210871018   1589210871018
REQUEST 6       POST /iam/v4/route/ 1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 7       POST /iam/v4/route/ 1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 8       POST /iam/v4/route/ 1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 9       POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 5       POST /iam/v4/route/ 1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 10      POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 2       POST /iam/v4/route/ 1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 3       POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 1       POST /iam/v4/route/ 1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 4       POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
USER    SSO 9   END 1589210870490   1589210871757
USER    SSO 11  START   1589210871764   1589210871764
USER    SSO 10  END 1589210871015   1589210871757
USER    SSO 12  START   1589210871771   1589210871771
USER    PRODUCT 3   END 1589210870459   1589210871765
USER    PRODUCT 13  START   1589210871778   1589210871778
USER    PRODUCT 4   END 1589210870983   1589210871765
USER    PRODUCT 14  START   1589210871783   1589210871783
USER    PROV    5   END 1589210870470   1589210871768
```

I am parsing the simulation.log file like shown below to get response times grouped by 'Scenario+RequestName'

```
RUN mock.CatSimulation  catsimulation   1589210870232       3.0.2
USER    AUTHZ   1   START   1589210870336   1589210870336
USER    PRODUCT 3   START   1589210870459   1589210870459
USER    PROV    5   START   1589210870470   1589210870470
USER    LDAP    7   START   1589210870479   1589210870479
USER    SSO 9   START   1589210870490   1589210870490
USER    AUTHZ   2   START   1589210870971   1589210870971
USER    PRODUCT 4   START   1589210870983   1589210870983
USER    PROV    6   START   1589210870993   1589210870993
USER    SSO 10  START   1589210871015   1589210871015
USER    LDAP    8   START   1589210871018   1589210871018
REQUEST 6       PROV POST /iam/v4/route/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 7       LDAP POST /iam/v4/route/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 8       LDAP POST /iam/v4/route/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 9       SSO POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 5       PROV POST /iam/v4/route/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 10      SSO POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 2       AUTHZ POST /iam/v4/route/   1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 3       PRODUCT POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 1       AUTHZ POST /iam/v4/route/   1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
REQUEST 4       PRODUCT POST /iam/v3/direct/    1589210871700   1589210871735   OK   
USER    SSO 9   END 1589210870490   1589210871757
USER    SSO 11  START   1589210871764   1589210871764
USER    SSO 10  END 1589210871015   1589210871757
USER    SSO 12  START   1589210871771   1589210871771
USER    PRODUCT 3   END 1589210870459   1589210871765
USER    PRODUCT 13  START   1589210871778   1589210871778
USER    PRODUCT 4   END 1589210870983   1589210871765
USER    PRODUCT 14  START   1589210871783   1589210871783
USER    PROV    5   END 1589210870470   1589210871768
```

Is there any option in Gatling to have scenario name in Request line entries ?

Comment: dev of karate here. no one has asked for this yet, perhaps because the `nameResolver` concept solves: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#nameresolver - I am not familiar with these files and how they are related to gatling groups. so if you can help us make enhancements by looking at the code and suggesting changes with examples etc, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

@Inquistive Engineer, maybe you could take a look at Gatling groups: they are made for such design (grouping requests in a block, related to the same goal).

https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#groups-definition

If it fits your needs, please note a recent fix have been done in karate-gatling, allowing to use groups & karate together

https://github.com/intuit/karate/pull/1468